# Certain modules cause the "Can't resolve all parameters" error?

Tags: angular, primeng, angular5, angular2-moment

I've noticed that some modules will cause my Angular 5 app to show the "can't resolve all parameters" error:

> EXCEPTION: Can't resolve all parameters for ApiService: (?).

I'd recently encountered this problem through other means and solved it by including this into my polyfills.ts:

```
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

The fix to this current problem is, of course, taking out the module from my app.module. Do these modules have something in common that can cause this error to occur?

The modules in question right now are [angular2-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment) and [PrimeNG's growls](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/growl). In the meantime I'll keep digging and report back if I find anything. Thank you for any help!!

**Update:** So it seems like I may have found the fix for PrimeNG; I'd forgotten to include:

```
"styles": [
        "styles/styles.scss",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/darkness/theme.css"
],
```

Into my .angular-cli.json file. Hooray! This makes me wonder if the "can't resolve all parameters" error isn't really very descriptive of the actual problem? I've seen one or two github issues about this, but they hadn't come to any solid conclusions.

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: @Rob Oh oops! Thank you. I'll remove it and include the code instead!